# How to run Python code on GPU without Numba?

Tags: python, gpu, point-clouds, lidar, open3d

I wanted to know that how to run Python code which uses 3rd party libraries on GPU.

I was thinking to use Numba and watched some videos on it, and came to know it would not "convert" 3rd party libraries. Particularly I am using Open3d in my Python code.